# Inserting a tick mark, as well as xlab in a barplot panel in r

Tags: r, graph

I would like to include tick marks in addition to `xlab` in a 3 by 3 panel of bar plots. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638633/set-different-positions-of-axis-labels-and-tick-marks-in-a-barplot) solution for a single graph, but somehow I had trouble replicating it. The idea is to label each of the bars with d that runs from -3 to +3, with a unit increase. The first bar in each plot represents the value of -3.  I tried to demonstrate my problem with a simulated data below. Any ideas?

```
# Data generation

# Populating a matrix
matrix(rnorm(63, 1:9), nrow=7, byrow=TRUE)

# Labelling the matrix
colnames(mat.s) <- c("Hs", "Sex", "Es", "Bo", "R", "W", "S", "Pri", "Abo")

# Tick mark indicator
d <- seq(-3,3,1)

# Plotting estimates
par(mfrow=c(3,3), mar = c(4,3,3,1))

for(i in 1:9) {

# Bar plot
barplot(mat.s[,i],

# X-label
xlab = colnames(mat.s)[i])

}
```

Comment: Does it have to base R? Can you show you implemented the solution?

Comment: To create the matrix, you can do `matrix(rnorm(63, 1:9), nrow=7, byrow=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify the `axis.lty`, `names.arg` and `mgp` inside the `barplot` function in the loop and you ll  be fine:

```
#I haven't changed anything else before the for-loop
#only changes have taken place inside the barplot function below
for(i in 1:9) {
  # Bar plot
  barplot(mat.s[,i], xlab = colnames(mat.s)[i], 
          names.arg= as.character(-3:3), axis.lty=1, mgp=c(3,1,0.2))
}
```

Output:

[image]

In a bit more detail:

- `names.arg` will add the labels
- `axis.lty=1` will add an x-axis
- `mgp` is a vector of length three that controls the margins of the title, the labels and the axis line in this order. I only needed to change the third element of that to 0.2 so that the axis looks nice (check `?par`).

Comment: You are very welcome @AlexRead :). Glad I could be of help !

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to LyzandeR's excellent answer is to add `axis()` after assigning the `barplot()` call to an object:

```
for(i in 1:9) {

  # Bar plot
  temp <- barplot(mat.s[,i],

  # X-label
  xlab = colnames(mat.s)[i])
  axis(1,at=temp,labels=-3:3)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `ggplot` version:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

# Add x-labels and reshape to long format then plot
ggplot(mat.s %>% mutate(x=-3:3) %>% melt(id.var="x"), 
       aes(x=x, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill=hcl(195,100,65)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable) +
  labs(x="", y="") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=-3:3)
```

[image]