# r - Fit heat map into grid lines on Calendar Heatmap

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, calendar, heat

I followed the example of a Calendar Heatmap shown in this [website](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html#Calendar%20Heat%20Map) (you have to scroll down to the Calendar Heat Map section)

Using example from website:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(scales)
library(zoo)

df <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/yahoo.csv")
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)  # format date
df <- df[df$year >= 2012, ]  # filter reqd years

# Create Month Week
df$yearmonth <- as.yearmon(df$date)
df$yearmonthf <- factor(df$yearmonth)
df <- ddply(df,.(yearmonthf), transform, monthweek=1+week-min(week))  # compute week number of month
df <- df[, c("year", "yearmonthf", "monthf", "week", "monthweek", "weekdayf", "VIX.Close")]

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(monthweek, weekdayf, fill = VIX.Close)) + 
  geom_tile(colour = "white") + 
  facet_grid(year~monthf) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green") +
  labs(x="Week of Month",
   y="",
   title = "Time-Series Calendar Heatmap", 
   subtitle="Yahoo Closing Price", 
   fill="Close")
```

This is the calendar heatmap you get.

[image]

I may be being exceptionally picky here, but is there a way that the bars can fit within the grid lines of the facets while keeping the labels at the midpoints?

I've tried using axis(), following advice from posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19638633/set-different-positions-of-axis-labels-and-tick-marks-in-a-barplot) but I think something gets lost when I try and translate it for the calendar heatmap.

Any advice would be brilliant, thank you!

Comment: Is `+ coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)` what you are after? I'm not sure exactly what you think isn't fitting.. Note that `axis` does not work in ggplot2.

Comment: Perhaps you want to turn of major grid lines and set minor breaks, but you need to convert to continuous scales then.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Axeman, unfortunately that didn't do the trick though. The Y grid lines go through the half way point of the coloured sections, and the X grid lines are too frequent (not the same width of the coloured section) and also go through the half way point. I expect it is something to do with the major/minor breaks but can't seem to solve it.

Comment: I've turned the grid lines off completely using  `+ theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),  panel.grid.major = element_blank())`  
That works but doesn't look as satisfying as if the grid lines fitted! :)